# Bookmarklet - grabbing videos from other sites

Tags: javascript, video, bookmarklet

I want to grab videos from other sites (youtube.com, vimeo.com)  via bookmarklet.

I have created bookmarklet. It works for "selectd text" and "images"  but how to do with videos?

Any Idea?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean grab? Cross domain restrictions mean it probably can't be done unless there's a JSON API or something similar.